# Can not count how many number of unique date are available in every part of string

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, stringbuilder

I divided my string in three part using newline ('\n'). The output that i want to achieve: count how many number of unique date are available in every part of string.
According to below code, first part contains two unique date, second part contains two and third part contains three unique date. So the output should be like this: 2,2,3,
But after run this below code i get this Output: 5,5,5,5,1,3,1,
How do i get Output: 2,2,3,
Thanks in advance.

```
        String strH;
        String strT = null;
        StringBuilder sbE = new StringBuilder();
        String strA = "2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-11,2021-03-11,2021-03-11,2021-03-11,2021-03-11," + '\n' +
                "2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-15,2021-03-15,2021-03-15,2021-03-15,2021-03-15," + '\n' +
                "2021-03-02,2021-03-09,2021-03-07,2021-03-09,2021-03-09,";

        String[] strG = strA.split("\n");
        for(int h=0; h<strG.length; h++){
            strH = strG[h];
            String[] words=strH.split(",");
            int wrc=1;
            for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++) {
                for(int j=i+1;j<words.length;j++) {
                    if(words[i].equals(words[j])) {
                        wrc=wrc+1;
                        words[j]="0";
                    }
                }
                if(words[i]!="0"){
                    sbE.append(wrc).append(",");
                    strT = String.valueOf(sbE);
                }
                wrc=1;
            }
        }
        Log.d("TAG", "Output: "+strT);
```

Comment: Your code is counting *duplicates*, but you need to count *distinct* values. I recommend you simply add the values to a `HashSet`, then get the set `size()`, since that will be the number of distinct values added to the set..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a set here to count the duplicates:

```java
String strA = "2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-11,2021-03-11,2021-03-11,2021-03-11,2021-03-11" + "\n" +
              "2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-15,2021-03-15,2021-03-15,2021-03-15,2021-03-15" + "\n" +
              "2021-03-02,2021-03-09,2021-03-07,2021-03-09,2021-03-09";
String[] lines = strA.split("\n");
List<Integer> counts = new ArrayList<>();
for (String line : lines) {
    counts.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split(","))).size());
}
System.out.println(counts);  // [2, 2, 3]
```

Note that I have done a minor cleanup of the `strA` input by removing the trailing comma from each line.

Comment: Awesome! Maybe you can use `line.split(",\\s*")` to deal with any whitespace after the comma. However, the question doesn't have any such requirement mentioned.

Comment: This is what i wanted. Thanks again...@Tim Biegeleisen

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 Streams, this can be done in a single statement:

```java
String strA = "2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-02,2021-03-11,2021-03-11,2021-03-11,2021-03-11,2021-03-11," + '\n' +
              "2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-07,2021-03-15,2021-03-15,2021-03-15,2021-03-15,2021-03-15," + '\n' +
              "2021-03-02,2021-03-09,2021-03-07,2021-03-09,2021-03-09,";

String strT = Pattern.compile("\n").splitAsStream(strA)
        .map(strG -> String.valueOf(Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(strG).distinct().count()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

System.out.println(strT); // 2,2,3
```

Note that `Pattern.compile("\n").splitAsStream(strA)` can also be written as `Arrays.stream(strA.split("\n"))`, which is shorter to write, but creates an unnecessary intermediate array. Matter of personal preference which is better.

```java
String strT = Arrays.stream(strA.split("\n"))
        .map(strG -> String.valueOf(Arrays.stream(strG.split(",")).distinct().count()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

The first version can be further micro-optimized by only compiling the regex once:

```java
Pattern patternComma = Pattern.compile(",");
String strT = Pattern.compile("\n").splitAsStream(strA)
        .map(strG -> String.valueOf(patternComma.splitAsStream(strG).distinct().count()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```